# Using the Graph API Explorer tool, how to specify complex parameters in HTTP Post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) how do you specify any of the parameters that are an object rather than just a string value when you click "add a field"? Things like arrays of objects such as `actions` field of the post (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)

Comment: In which scenarios, you want to send an object through post? Can you provide any example or any specific GRAPH call ?

Comment: `\me\feed` is an example, but Alex Blex below answered my question perfectly...although they didn't need the PHP example in there too, but that's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is a json object.

for example from [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/3429737/1110423)

```
$attachment = array('message' => 'this is my message',
                'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
                'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
                'link' => 'http://mylink.com',
                'description' => 'this is a description',
                'picture' => 'http://mysite.com/pic.gif',
                'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Get Search',
                                  'link' => 'http://www.google.com'))
                );
    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/',
                                'post',
                                $attachment);
```

your `actions` field in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) is

`[{"name":"Get Search","link":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}]`

Comment: Is there any way for images also (with source field not url)?